# Is there a way to make a dictionary from a single line input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, graph

I'm trying to solve a problem that needs all entries to be in one single line input. The number of entries is also made by an input. These entries represent vertices of a directed graph.

Initially I thought about trying to solve with list, then convert the list to a dictionary, which would be the adjacency list:

```
n = int(input())
lst = str(input()).strip().split(" ")
lst = [int(i) for i in lst]
if len(lst) != n:
     print('The number of entries is invalid!')
```

But I don't know how to proceed in the part of transforming the list into a dictionary.

Examples: my first input `n = "3"` it means i will have 3 entries, so if my next entries are `2 3 2`, the list would be `lst = ['2', '3', '2']`, the dictionary would be `{2: 3, 3: 2}`. The first input number would be the root, and the next would be the adjacent number of the previous number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up adjacent elements of the list, and then use the `dict()` constructor to turn that into a dictionary.

```
d = dict(zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

Comment: thanks! just one more question: what if i need to turn the dictionary value into a list? example: {2: [3], 3: [2]}

Comment: `d = dict(zip(lst, ([x] for x in lst[1:])))`

Comment: hey! i found a problem. in a situation where my inputs are 2 3 2 4 1, the result should be {2: [3, 4], 3: [2], 4: [1]}, but it ended up being {2: [4], 3: [2], 4: [1]}, that is, the last value overlaps what already exists. how can i solve this?

Comment: You need to write a loop that checks whether the key is already in the dictionary. Either create a new entry or append to the list depending.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a list comprehension, you can do a dictionary comprehension:

```
theList = [3, 2,4, 5,6, 8,9]
myDict = {theList[i]:theList[i+1] for i in range(1,2*theList[0])}
```

(I'm using here the first number of the list as N, so only one input is needed)